# How do I plot the DC equivalent of an AC sinusoidal signal in Python?

Tags: signal-processing, python

I want to draw a line that bisects an AC signal as seen in the first picture below. This line should take into consideration any drifts.

So essentially, I have an AC voltage signal over time for 3 devices and I want to plot the DC equivalent (Please see the first picture below).

[image]

The AC signal for 2 of the devices show a general upward trend (drift) in time and the last one shows a downard drift. The frequency I'm using is 1 Hz. Amplitude is 50 μA. I've been struggling with how to approach the plotting of this data a while now. In the end, I want a graph that looks something like the graph below representing the DC equivalent of the AC time series voltage data:

[image]

This is how I'm approaching it so far:

1. Load the data.
2. Remove outlier data.
3. Calculate the RMS for each wave form then connect them.

Please let me know if I'm approaching this the right way. I will really appreciate your advice. I'm happy to attach dummy data.

Comment: first, define what "the DC equivalent of an AC signal" means. Equivalent in terms of what?

Comment: Jeff Kyei - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the site rules in the [tour] & [help]. (b) Please note that PC programming, which is what your question's title implies, is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) here, although I expect it'll be on-topic somewhere else on Stack Exchange (perhaps on Stack Overflow, where I see you already have an account). To reduce the chances of your question being closed as off-topic here, please make sure to constrain your question to aspects that are on-topic. Thanks.

Comment: @hobbs equivalent in terms of the magnitude of the current. or perhaps, let me say an imaginary line that cuts through the AC voltage waveform in half.

Comment: @hobbs I've editted my post by attaching picture to demonstrate my point!

Comment: @JeffKyei can you explain how your question is specifically about EE when in fact, the data you are trying to plot could be from a weather monitor representing windspeed and therefore more clearly not an EE question. Just because it relates to voltage in some passing way, does not make it a valid question for this site.

Comment: Seems like a pretty clear signal processing question to me, and clearly on topic.

Comment: [Stack exchange signal processing site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-processing

Comment: It's unclear if what drifts is AC amplitude or just the DC offset. You could simply filter away high enough AC frequencies that leave the slow AC frequency of DC drift intact. A simple 1st order weighted average filter will simulate an RC filter. Better options such as 2nd order biquads and FIR and IIR filtering exists, if you go deep down to signal processing.

Comment: @Justme what do you think about this image, please? https://ibb.co/Qk2Z108

Here are the steps I took: https://ctxt.io/2/AADQEP2AFg
BTW I'm not applying any DC offset. Just AC current amplitude

Answer (score 2):

"RMS" is one number, which is certainly not what you want.  What you want is probably a rolling average.  Take a window a certain number of points wide (say from point 1 to point n), and calculate the mean.  Increment by one point (say from point 2 to point n+1), and repeat.  Keep going until you hit the end.

There will obviously be artifacts associated with the data boundaries (near the beginning and end of your record).

This is a specific form of what we call a "Finite Impulse Response (FIR) Filter".  It has low-pass characteristics.  If instead of a simple mean, you use a weighted average, you can tune your filters to different frequency responses.

Filtering is somewhat of an art.  There are many kinds of filters (you want something from the family of "low-pass" filters, which remove higher frequency components from a record, but leave the low frequency information).  They can get very complicated.  My recommendation is to start with the simple rolling average I described.  Start with a small n for the window width, and make n bigger until you get what you want.

If you want to get a bit more adventurous, there are a host of ways to implement low-pass filters in python.  See https://www.samproell.io/posts/yarppg/digital-filters-python/, for example.  The cutoff frequency with respect to the AC signal predominant frequency of the example filter is higher than what you're trying to accomplish, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I appreciate your insight. How will I account for the fact that the general trend for 2 of the devices is upwards whiles the trend for another is downloads? perhaps take the magnitude of the mean?

Comment: @JeffKyei  you do each signal separately, and you don't need to worry about the direction of the trend.  The filter will follow.  I recommend starting with n set to the number of points in about 1 period of your AC predominant frequency, and move up from there.

Comment: what do you think about this image, please? https://ibb.co/Qk2Z108

Here are the steps I took: https://ctxt.io/2/AADQEP2AFg

Comment: @JeffKyei -  I don't follow links from people I don't know.  If there's an update to the question, just add to the question by editing it.  Don't do anything to the original part of the question, though - that messes with continuity

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the data in Octave or Python (nympy, scipy, etc) using signal processing toolboxes.

Or maybe in C or whatever language.

A 1st order IIR filter that simulates an electronic RC low pass filter is simple to implement, even Wikipedia can be used as a resource.

Comment: what do you think about this image, please? https://ibb.co/Qk2Z108

Here are the steps I took: https://ctxt.io/2/AADQEP2AFg

Answer (score 0):

If you want something close to DC then use a [high pass filter in python](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-filter-noise-with-a-low-pass-filter-python-885223e5e9b7) with a pole close to DC.

Median filters that take the average value also might be of use to the application